# Adding the sum of 6 Dice, how do you calculate the permutations?

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations, dice

By working out the different combinations for the sum being 6,7 and 8, (1, 6, and 21) I can see this is a diagonal row in pascals triangle but I can’t work out how these would be calculated without the assistance of the triangle once the numbers start getting larger? I have tried to look at what numbers can be added together like with 8, you can have 3,1,1,1,1,1 and change the position of 3 (ie, 1,3,1,1,1,1 also counts towards the amount of ways you can get the sum of 8) and you can the have 2,2,1,1,1,1 and change the position of the two 2’s. I’m finding I tend to miss out some ways of adding numbers together as the number gets bigger so was just wondering if I’m going about this by the right method and to keep going if I know what numbers I’m meant to be getting, or if there’s another way of going about this?

In lectures, we did and example where we had 6 coins and we calculated the probability of getting x amount of heads. It was noted to us that it came from Pascal’s triangle so I am aware it’s from the combinations and permutations area but this is the only reason I looked at the triangle once I had calculated some values for this question!

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is $3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1$ considered to be different from $1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1$? Because if they are considered the same, then what you have is a problem of [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)). They are notoriously difficult in general.

Comment: No, I believe they are different as in the example in lectures for 1 heads, it could be any of the 5 coins

Comment: Ok. Then [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) will get you the answer you seek. At least until you reach $12$, which has a complication in that you can't throw $7$ on a die.

Comment: Ah ok, thank you! 12 was where I was beginning to have problems which is probably why

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I haven’t got a formula, but I have noticed for that for example in 11, if you have four dice with value 1, the other two dice must add to make 7, so 6 and 1, 5 and 2, 3 and 4. And it’s the same sort of thing when you set three dice to having the value 1, the other three must add to give the value 8, so like 4,2,2 would work. Is this what you mean? So say the sum of the dice we’re looking at is x, when you fix 4 dice at 1 you need the two dice to add to x-4?

Comment: Your question's title says $5$ dice, but your numbers indicate that you are using $6$ dice.

Comment: @DanielMathias we have a question for 5 and 6, hence the confusion! Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: For a sum of at most $11$, you wish to solve the equation $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 = 11$ in the positive integers.  The number of solutions of the equation $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_k = n$ in the positive integers is given by the formula $\binom{n - 1}{k - 1}$.  See Theorem 1 in the second link Arthur provided.